# What is concrete meaning of replica in DeviceSpec

Tags: python, tensorflow

In class [tf.DeviceSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#DeviceSpec), there is a field **Replica**. Also in tensorflow logs, we can see some messages such as "**/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0**". Anybody can tell me what the concrete meaning of replica is and how I should use it?

Comment: Have you read this page? It is good start point. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html

Comment: Yes, I did read this page and tried to use tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer for replicated training. But I just found logs about replica:0. Do you know where replica:[1~n] will be used?

Comment: You can ignore the replica field and just use job and task. I don't think anything relies on the meaning of replica.